# SetWindowPos insert AFTER, not before?

Tags: c#, winapi, overlay

Okay so I'm trying to overlay my form on top of another application. Now, as the final step I need to make sure my form's z-index is always one above the application I'm overlaying. I'm pretty sure I need to use SetWindowPos (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do so, and it has a parameter that allows me to set the window's z-index. However, it only allows me to set it to the z-index under the application I'm trying to overlay. How could I use the function to overlay the application instead? The parameter I'm talking about is the `hWndInsertAfter` parameter.

This is how I'm using the code now (which underlays the form):
`SetWindowPos(this.Handle, clientHandle, clientTopLeft.X, clientTopLeft.Y, clientWidth, clientHeight, SWP.SHOWWINDOW);`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Ah so the answer was blatantly obvious... I just needed to use the same function, but reverse the first two parameters to underlay the other application under mine.

This is the code I used:

```
SetWindowPos(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, clientTopLeft.X, clientTopLeft.Y, clientWidth, clientHeight, SWP.SHOWWINDOW);
SetWindowPos(clientHandle, this.Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP.NOMOVE | SWP.NOSIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: If you want to insert hwndA above hwndB, then you can

- call `hwndHigher=GetNextWindow(hwndB, GW_HWNDPREV)` to find out the existing HWND above hwndB ;
- then call `SetWindowPos` to insert hwndA after hwndHigher, and your goal is achieved.

A special case is `hwndHigher==NULL`, that means hwndB is already at top of z-order, then you should instead call `SetWindowPos` with `HWND_TOP` to make hwndA at top.